# Python Returning Appropriate Type From a String

Tags: python, types

Let's say there is string that needs to be converted into a appropriate type.
For example, if the string is:
"1.0" return to `1.0 <type 'float'>`
"[1.0, 2.1, 3]" return to `[1.0, 2.1, 3] <type 'list'>`

Is there a smart way of doing this?

Comment: what you mean exactly by smart way ?

Comment: I think you're trying to re-implement a portion of Python in Python.  You might be able to use something like `eval()`.  However, this sounds like you're trying to solve some other problem and this is most likely not the best way to do it.  You should probably ask about what you're actually trying to do.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
import ast
val = ast.literal_eval(input_str)
print type(val)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is exactly what I was looking for. I didn't want to use lots of if and else statements to figure out the type.